# Is there a solfege audio course which I can buy?

Tags: self-learning, solfege

I want to learn solfege, but cannot take private lessons at the moment. I tried looking on YouTube and haven't found anything. Is there a course I can buy online?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Vtc for the same reasons that apply to your last question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know that.